# Knockout Js update ViewModel when data attribute is updated

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using jQuery UI Sortable with KnockoutJS ViewModel.

I have an array inside a ViewModel, which is used to Display a Div, and User can sort those divs by jQueryUI Sortable.

I have created a Similar scenario in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swscgvvh/2/

```
ko.applyBindings({
    items: [{
        ThisText: 'Bert',
        index: 1
    }, {
        ThisText: 'Charles',
        index: 2
    }, {
        ThisText: 'Denise',
        index: 3
    }]
});


$(function () {
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        forceHelperSize: true,
        revert: true,
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var sorter = $(this);
            var sortables = sorter.children();

            sortables.each(function (i) {
                // HERE I Update the data-id attribute
                $(sortables[i]).attr('data-id', i + 1);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

On this line of the Code: `$(sortables[i]).attr('data-id', i + 1);`

I am updating the attr: `data-id`, of the div. but this is not taking affect in the ViewModel.

If you do an Inspect Element on the Div, the `data-id=3` when `Charles` is moved to 3rd Position.

[image]

Comment: a vote for close? Why?

Comment: I would post an answer but this blog post has a lot of useful information so i will just share it instead.. http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/dragging-dropping-and-sorting-with.html in short though, your situation requires a bindingHandler which is covered in the link.

Comment: @DawoodAwan Someone vtc'ed as "too broad". The question is slightly chaotic, but I think it isn't too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing - if you will change attribute this will not update underlying ViewModel (and this is correct, idea to update attribite from code to change ViewModel is against concept of MVVM pattern - in your code you should change ViewModel, and knockout will update View for you).

Regarding yor example, you have 2 issues:

index is plain integer, you should define it as observable, i.e.

```
index: ko.observable(1)
```

Instead of updating data-id, you should use ko.dataFor utility function, and update ViewModel:

```
ko.dataFor(this).index(i+1);
```

Whole sample:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/682fhx1a/)

```
ko.applyBindings({
    items: ko.observableArray([{
        ThisText: 'Bert',
        index: ko.observable(1)
    }, {
        ThisText: 'Charles',
        index: ko.observable(2)
    }, {
        ThisText: 'Denise',
        index: ko.observable(3)
    }])
});


$(function () {
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        forceHelperSize: true,
        revert: true,
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var sorter = $(this);
            var sortables = sorter.children();

            sortables.each(function (i) {
                // HERE I Update the data-id attribute
                ko.dataFor(this).index(i+1);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE: Also consider using plugin [knockout-dragdrop](https://github.com/One-com/knockout-dragdrop), it supports sorting as well - see [examples](http://one-com.github.io/knockout-dragdrop/examples/) - it is much better than mixing JQuery UI Sortable with Knockout.

Answer (score 0):

This because your jquery script is running before the html Dom is ready.
You can put your anonimous function inside "setTimeout". This is bad practice but will work

Comment: My jQuery is working fine, it updates the data-id attribute, the ViewModel is not updating

Comment: You update attribute of DOM element, which effect you want be happen in your view model?

Comment: yes, I am binding using Knockout::  data-bind="attr: {'data-id': index}"

Comment: The "data-id" is rendered by knockout array index, and after that is changed by jquery on html DOM. You can't react knockout viewModel by changing your DOM element, using jquery